# Using only one js file for multiple php ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

First of all, my intention is to have 1 js file where there are multiple ajax calls. I want these ajax calls, which are php files, to have the same js file inside of it but not doing another request, which makes it to run slow after any click.

Some of my main php file:

```
<head>
    <script src="<?php echo $_SESSION['url'] ?>js/direcinfo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="direcciones">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="c_menu_direcciones" class="c-menu c_menu_direcciones">
            <p>
              Direcciones
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="cuenta_menu_direcciones" class="c-menu-content">
        <h1>Direcciones de correo</h1>
        <div id="expand_wrapper_dir">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Js file (`direcinfo.js`):

```
$('#c_menu_direcciones').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      dataType: "html",
      type: "POST",
      url: "direcalias.php",
      success: function(cntnt){
      $("#expand_wrapper_dir").html(cntnt);
    }
    });
    return false;
});

$(".alias-dir-a").click(function(){
    var useremail=$("#useremail").val();
    var alias=$(this).html();
    if(alias==="+")
    {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            url: "direcnew.php",
            data: "email="+useremail,
            success: function(cntnt){
                $("#direc-content").html(cntnt);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Ajax loaded file (`direcalias.php`)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
    include_once 'connection.php';
    $conn = bbddconnect();
    $email=$_SESSION['useremail'];
    $query = "SELECT CODIDIR,ALIAS"
            . " FROM CLIENTE C,DIRECCION D"
            . " WHERE EMAIL LIKE '$email' AND C.CODICNT = D.CODICNT;"; 

    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
    $recount = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
    echo '<div class="menu-alias madir">';
        for($i=0;$i<$recount;$i++)
        {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);

    echo '<div class="alias adir ali-'.$i.'">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="alias-dir-a">'.$row['ALIAS'].'</a>
    </div>';

        }

    echo '<div class="alias adir ali-nuevo">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="alias-dir-a">+</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="direc-content"></div>';

    //echo '<script>'.
    //            'var url = "'.$_SESSION['url'].'js/direcinfo.js";'.
    //            '$.getScript(url);'.
    //    '</script>';

?>
```

The problem I have is that when the `direcalias.php` file is called I need to call the js file again (edited part) because if I don't, it does not recognize when I click on `$(".alias-dir-a").click(function())`. Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: You can try `$("#direc-content").on('click',  ".alias-dir-a", function(){`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It beacuse you call `.alias-dir-a` before it create. you can use `on` method

```
$(document).on("click", ".alias-dir-a", function() {

    var useremail=$("#useremail").val();
    var alias=$(this).html();
    if(alias==="+")
    {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            url: "direcnew.php",
            data: "email="+useremail,
            success: function(cntnt){
                $("#direc-content").html(cntnt);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you